# Aspose.Pdf: Why are Chinese characters "Blanked Out"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, aspose, chinese-locale

I am using a PDF generation library called Aspose.Pdf. I love this library, but I am having a problem getting Chinese characters to show up in a PDF. I am using the following code to generate the PDF in C#.NET MVC:

```
var pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
pdf.IsLandscape = true;
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingLevelOfForce = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.HtmlInfo.CharsetApplyingForceLevel.EnforceUseAlways;
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharSet = "UTF-8";
pdf.HtmlInfo.BadHtmlHandlingStrategy = Aspose.Pdf.Generator.BadHtmlHandlingStrategy.TreatAsPlainText;
pdf.BindHTML(htmlString);
pdf.SetUnicode();
pdf.Save(fullFilePath);
```

The value inside the htmlString variable is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS',Arial,sans-serif; ">
    <center><h3>Corrective Action Plans PDF</h3></center>
    <table style="padding: 5px; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid #000000;" cellpadding="5">
            <tr style="border: 1px solid #000000;" bgcolor="#4D94FF">
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        审计类型
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        审核表格
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Category
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        问题
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Location ID
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Location
                    </th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Start Date
                    </th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid #000000;" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        1260
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        New
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        CAM Forms
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        CAM Form 4 - All Action Plan Options
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        CAM4: Use Action Plan
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        Droplist Non-Compliant
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        017
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        ANGLETON
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;" width="11%">
                        2014/2/13 14:00:00
                    </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are Chinese characters in the HTML markup, in the header row of the table. But, the values are being "blanked out" in the resulting PDF document.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a pretty specific question, so I wasn't sure I would even get a response to this at all. But, I was desperate, and so reached out anyway. :)

In any case, I pushed through and managed to find a solution to this. I fixed it by changing my C# to the following:

```
var pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
pdf.IsLandscape = true;

Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Section section = pdf.Sections.Add();
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Text text = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Text(section, htmlString);
text.IsHtmlTagSupported = true;
text.IsHtml5Supported = true;
text.TextInfo.FontName = "Arial Unicode MS";
text.IfHtmlTagSupportedOverwriteHtmlFontNames = true;
section.Paragraphs.Add(text);
pdf.SetUnicode();

pdf.Save(fullFilePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, but with much different setup.
I'm not using BindHTML and HTML data, instead of that, I use XML input:

```
var pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
pdf.BindXML(thexml);
pdf.Save(fullFilePath);
```

where `thexml` contains a long and complicated description of how the PDF objects should be generated. All along Aspose PDF XML specs, all working. Except for when some inner text or inner html data contained non-Latin characters.

I tried with Cyrillics, Japanese and Polish examples - In all 'special' characters in the first two were rendered as blank spaces, in Polish all special characters were coerced to closest Latin characters (ć->c, Ł->L and so on).

Btw. I use Aspose.PDF v9.6.0.0

With help of this question/answers, I was able to get it **somewhat** working with:

```
var pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf();
pdf.TextInfo.IsUnicode = true;
pdf.SetUnicode();
pdf.BindXML(thexml);
pdf.Save(fullFilePath);
```

Other settings you presented didn't seem to change anything. Also, it's curious that I had to set IsUnicode twice as you see. `SetUnicode` was not enough.

With the above, Cyrillic and Polish are OK, but Japanese is still blank. Still, this is enough for me for now. Maybe it will fork fine for someone too.